# Can OTPs substitute password?

Tags: authentication, passwords, multi-factor, one-time-password

One-time passwords (OTPs) usually serve as the 2nd factor in a 2FA scheme. But, in isolation, I believe they are more secure than passwords, since they are ephemeral and passwords are still badly reused in the wild. Unless end-to-end encryption or some strict usability issue is involved, I can't really see a case where passwords are superior.

From my experience, the current state of affairs in authentication is:

- Virtually every service demands password for authentication.
- Some allow users to turn on 2FA, which is usually done by OTPs.
- Few support "passwordless" authentication, meaning an OTP is sent to an email. I use quotes here because this is a misnomer. Users still need a password, but to a different service (their email).

What I have never seen is a service that allows OTP only authentication. In this case, a password could very well serve as the 2nd factor.

Is there any particular security reason for why is this the case?

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37203/what-are-the-security-implications-of-using-totp-for-single-factor-authenticatio

Comment: This has been asked a few times.

Comment: The short answer is that TOTP is not designed to be a primary factor and hence is not secured  to be such. You could re-engineer the process to be more secure, but then you are designing something different. PAM tools do this type of thing (ephemeral passwords) but are not designed for public enrollment.

Comment: @schroeder thanks for the pointers and summary. Too bad all those answers are heavily opinion based and unconvincing. I guess I'll need to resort to academic stuff to see if anyone researched that.

Comment: Why do you need "academic" studies? The protocols and definitions are enough.  https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6238 The seed is not protected in the same way that passwords are.

Comment: @schroeder that's is indeed a convincing answer that I was unable to find in any of the other questions, which I would accept had my question not been closed. Thank you very much!

Comment: About the academic stuff, I still wonder if a well designed OTP-as-a-single-factor is better than passwords, so maybe there are some empirical studies out there. My (probably wrong) intuition is that password reuse is still a massive problem that OTP would effectively solve without many drawbacks.

Comment: There are empirical studies on ephemeral passwords. But you are trying to use TOTP in a way it simply wasn't designed to. Your academic research appears to be occurring backwards. You are trying to fit research into what you hope is already true.

Comment: That's why, enlightened by your comment, I used the term "well designed OTP-as-a-single-factor". Maybe what I really meant is ephemeral passwords, as you call it.

Comment: @sourcream Why bother with a a "well designed OTP-as-a-single-factor" if you could use a standard like [FIDO2](https://fidoalliance.org/fido2/), specially since I suspect a "well designed OTP-as-a-single-factor" will end up looking pretty similiar to FIDO2 anyways?

Comment: @nobody what bothers me isn't exactly what's the best authentication scheme out there, but why OTPs are treated as second class citizens compared to passwords, given the latter has the potential of being reused. Whether FIDO2 can be a good substitute for both is a good question, but it's not the one I'm asking here.

Comment: @sourcream Well, its just that the OTPs we are currently use (i.e TOTP) aren't designed to be safe as a single factor, both because the seeds are not protected and because the 6-digit codes are not entirely [resistant to brute force](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/185917/235964). Could we design as safe 1fa OTP? Probably yes, but since there is no existing standard for it, I doubt there are studies comparing something that is not defined against passwords.